# How to make touch.locationInNode() recognize the difference between a node and its child?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, touchesbegan

I started out by declaring two SKSpriteNodes, handle and blade, and adding handle as a child of self, and blade as a child of handle

```
var handle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Handle.png")
var blade = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Blade.png")

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    handle.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height / 14)
    blade.position = CGPointMake(0, 124)

    self.addChild(Handle)
    Handle.addChild(Blade)
}
```

When I click on the handle, it prints to the console "Handle was clicked", however when I click on the Blade, it also prints "Handle was clicked". It is clearly recognizing that the blade is a child of handle, but how can I make it so when I click on blade, it prints "Blade was clicked"?

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if (Handle.containsPoint(location)){
            NSLog("Handle was clicked")
        }
        else if (Blade.containsPoint(location)){
            NSLog("Blade was clicked")
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You can differentiate by using assigning unique name properties for each node and checking for the node's name in the touchesBegan method.

Comment: But that's exactly what I did, and it didn't work. I named one of them handle, and the other blade, and when I clicked on blade it thought I was clicking on handle

Comment: Hello again @Lahav. You are right because it is a child you can't use `containsPoint` because it is basically using the frame of the sprite and looking to see if the point in scene coordinate system matches a point in one of its children, but you want the children of the children. Never fear help is on the way! Either myself or one of the Sprite Kit Alliance members will help out soon. Plz stand by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Determining whether the user touched the sword's handle or the blade is fairly straightforward with some caveats. The following assumes that 1. the sword image is facing to the right when `zRotation = 0`, 2. the `anchorPoint` of the sword is (0, 0.5), and 3. the sword (blade and handle) is a single sprite node. When you add a sprite to another sprite, the size of the parent's frame expands to include the child node. That's why your test of `Handle.containsPoint` is true no matter where you click on the sword.

The figure below shows a sword sprite with a dark gray handle (on the left) and lighter gray blade. The black rectangle surrounding the sword represents the sprite's frame and the circle represents the location of the user's touch. The length of the line labeled `a` is the distance from the touch point to the bottom of the sword. We can test this distance to see if the user touched the handle (if `a <= handleLength`) or the blade (if `a > handleLength`). When `zRotation = 0`, `a = x` so the test is `x <= handleLength`, where the bottom of the sword is `x = 0`.

[image]

In the below figure, the sword is rotated by 90 degree (i.e., `zRotation = M_PI_2`). Similarly, if `a <= handleLength`, the user touched the handle, else the user touched the blade. The only difference is `a` is now the `y` value instead of `x` due to the sword's rotation. In both cases, the frame's bounding box can be used, as is, to detect if the user touched the sword.

[image]

When the sprite is rotated by 45 degree, however, its frame automatically expands to enclose the sprite as shown by the black rectangle in the figure below. Consequently, when the user touches anywhere in the rectangle, the test `if sprite.frame.contains(location)` will be true. This may result in the user picking up the sword when the location of the touch is relatively far from the sword (i.e., when the distance `b` is large). If we want the maximum touch distance to be the same across all rotation angles, additional testing is required.

[image]

The good news is Sprite Kit provides a way to convert from one coordinate system to another. In this case, we need to convert from scene coordinates to the sword coordinates. This greatly simplifies the problem because it also rotates the point to the new coordinate system. After converting from scene to sword coordinates, the converted touch location's `x` and `y` values are the same as the distances `a` and `b` over all rotation angles! Now that we know `a` and `b`, we can determine how close the touch was to the sword and whether the user touched the handle or the blade.

From the above, we can implement the following code:

```
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    // Check if the user touched inside of the sword's frame (see Figure 1-3)
    if (sword.frame.contains(location)) {
        // Convert the touch location from scene to sword coordinates
        let point = sword.convertPoint(location, fromNode: self)
        // Check if the user touched any part of the sword. Note that a = point.x and b = point.y
         if (fabs(point.y) < sword.size.height/2 + touchTolerance) {
             // Check if the user touched the handle
             if (point.x <= handleLength) {
                 println("touched handle")
             }
             else {
                 println("touched blade")
             }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work without changing too much of your existing code...

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {

        let locationInScene = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let locationInHandel = touch.locationInNode(Handle)

        if (Blade.containsPoint(locationInHandel)){

            NSLog("Blade was clicked")

        }
        else if (Handle.containsPoint(locationInScene)){

            NSLog("Handle was clicked")

        }

    }
}
```

Note you are checking for blade first then you check for handle. Also note you have to convert the touchpoint to give you a point from within handle.

With that being said this will work on a small scale, but you may want to look at creating a subclass for SKSpriteNode called Handle or Sword (this is why you don't use first caps for variable names they are normally only use first caps for classes), set it to userInteractionEnabled and then override touchesBegan in that subclass and see if it is touching the blade and if not you know it touched the handle.

Hopefully that helped and made sense.